dbt transformation - pivoting
I have below as source_data in oracle database,
{{ config(materialized='table') }}

with source_data as (
    select 
        sd.field_value,
        af.adco_field_name
    from 
        {{ source('adco', 'sow_src_data') }} sd
        join {{ source('adco', 'src_field') }} sf on sd.src_field_id = sf.src_field_id
        join {{ source('adco', 'src_mapping') }} sm on sm.src_field_id = sf.src_field_id
        join {{ source('adco', 'adco_field') }} af on af.adco_field_id = sm.adco_field_id
    where 
        effective_date = '2024-02-08'
),

I want to pivot the source_data to make adco_field_name rows as columns and corresponding field_value as values for each column.
source_data sample, provided only five rows for simplicity, the actual dataset contains more than 100 rows, making it impractical to hardcode the `ADCO_FIELD_NAME`
ADCO_FIELD_NAME | FIELD_VALUE
--------------- | -----------
SV6M10YP        | 15.7
LIBOR180        | 7.95
LIBOR240        | 8.02
Cofi11          | 11.848

Expected output,
SV6M10YP | LIBOR180 | LIBOR240 | Cofi11
---------|----------|----------|---------
15.7     | 7.95     | 8.02     | 11.848

If the above process is tedious to achieve in Oracle, then the Microsoft SQL Server (MSSQL) approach is also acceptable.
I am trying to achieve the pivoted output but unable to produce the expected result.

You can try using Oracle Pivot functionality with run_query dbt macro. I'm assuming that you put your source_data query into a separate dbt model.
{% set field_names_query %}
SELECT DISTINCT adco_field_name FROM {{ ref('source_data') }}
{% endset %}

{% set results = run_query(field_names_query) %}

{% if execute %}
{% set results_list = results.columns[0].values() %}
{% else %}
{% set results_list = [''] %}
{% endif %}

SELECT * FROM {{ ref('source_data') }}
PIVOT
  (
  MAX(FIELD_VALUE)
  FOR ADCO_FIELD_NAME IN (
    {% for field_name in results_list %}
    '{{ field_name }}' {% if not loop.last %},{% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
    )
  )

